# MAX of one column with corresponding columns in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

This is a small portion of what I have in my table, there are multiple dates, but this is just for one date:

```
propertyId groupId  date         quantity rate
------------------------------------------------
3475       616375   2018-09-21   25       139.99
3475       626696   2018-09-21   6        144.99
3475       602361   2018-09-21   25       134.99
3475       622321   2018-09-21   5        119.99
3482       609348   2018-09-21   11       139.99
3482       621872   2018-09-21   5        75
3482       614956   2018-09-21   25       114.99
3482       583585   2018-09-21   10       139
3488       627286   2018-09-21   11       164.99
3488       619219   2018-09-21   5        129.99
3488       603781   2018-09-21   2        149.99
3488       583573   2018-09-21   2        0
```

I need the `MAX(quantity)` with the corresponding `propertyId`, `groupId`, `date`, and `rate`...the minimum rate if the quantity is a tie...and finally the `SUM(quantity)` for each day by property, not group.

From the sample I would need:

```
propertyId groupId  date         quantity rate    sumQuantity
--------------------------------------------------------------
3475       616375   2018-09-21   25       134.99  61
3482       614956   2018-09-21   25       114.99  51
3488       627286   2018-09-21   11       164.99  20
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Data feed for testing:

```
set dateformat ymd
declare @aux table (propertyId int, groupId int,[date] datetime, quantity int, rate money)
insert into @aux values (3475,616375,'2018-09-21',25,139.99)
insert into @aux values (3475,626696,'2018-09-21',6,144.99)
insert into @aux values (3475,602361,'2018-09-21',25,134.99)
insert into @aux values (3475,622321,'2018-09-21',5,119.99)
insert into @aux values (3482,609348,'2018-09-21',11,139.99)
insert into @aux values (3482,621872,'2018-09-21',5,75)
insert into @aux values (3482,614956,'2018-09-21',25,114.99)
insert into @aux values (3482,583585,'2018-09-21',10,139)
insert into @aux values (3488,627286,'2018-09-21',11,164.99)
insert into @aux values (3488,619219,'2018-09-21',5,129.99)
insert into @aux values (3488,603781,'2018-09-21',2,149.99)
insert into @aux values (3488,583573,'2018-09-21',2,0)
```

Proposed solution:

```
select a.*
    ,(select sum(quantity)
        from @aux
        where [date] = a.[date]
            and propertyId = a.propertyId
     ) sumQuantity
from @aux a
join (
    select x.*
        ,(select max(rate)
            from @aux
            where [date] = x.[date]
                and propertyId = x.propertyId
                and quantity = x.qt
            ) rt
    from (select [date]
            ,propertyId
            ,max(quantity) as qt
        from @aux
        group by [date], propertyId
        ) x
    ) b on a.[date] = b.[date]
    and a.propertyid = b.propertyid
    and qt = a.quantity
    and rt = a.rate
```